# Same code acting differently on different devices?

Tags: java, android, vibration

Would there be any reason for code running differently on a Samsung device than it was run on a Vodafone or another Android device.

I have checked that:

- Same APK
- Same versions of Android
- All app permissions are the same

The difference is that the Samsung is not following the vibrate pattern that I have set but the Vodafone phone is running it perfectly.

Here is the vibration code:

```
if (!this.isRunning && startId == 1) {
        Log.e("if there was not sound", " and you want to start");
        //incorporate vibrating
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        long[] pattern = {0, 15000, 0, 15000};
        v.vibrate(pattern, -1);
```

I simply just want the phone to vibrate for 30 seconds without any breaks but the Samsung phone is stopping for 5 seconds then resuming which is completely out of character from the code I have used... any ideas?

Comment: @Michael Dodd... any ideas instead of edits?

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity add this below code in Oncreate method after setcontentView();

```
  int PERMISSION_ALL = 1; 

  String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.VIBRATE};

        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
```

then add this function in your class

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) { 

  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {    

        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it like this and it does not work on either Vodafone or Samsung device which is really weird.. seems to maximum go for 15 seconds when I have specified 30000 milliseconds @Waqar Abbas

Comment: @Tom Aranda.. any ideas?

Comment: have you added permission like this in android.xml                               <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

Comment: Yes.. the code is correct and all working as shows on Vodafone handset but Samsung does not it stops inbetween?? how can this be

Comment: Yes the permission is there

Comment: what is your mobile model and android version?

Comment: I have 2 samsung devices.. one is Samsung galaxy j3 Android 7.0 API 24, other is galaxy j7 prime Android 6.0 API 23.. it does not work on either correctly.. but works correctly on a Vodafone smart ultra 7 Android 6.0 API 23

Comment: One more thing please add the code outside this if condition and check its working or not.

Comment: I got your problem . As android 6.0 and above need run time permissions . So I am updating the answer with code please try this code and your problem is solved

Comment: it worked but only for about 10 seconds when I set it to 30000 which should be 30 seconds

Comment: it is not resolving .VIBRATE or !haspermissions

Comment: add this  at  top    import android.Manifest;

Comment: remove any import using manifest in top before and then add this import

Comment: have you got it?

Comment: got it or I will send you image?

Comment: I have added inyour code with the permission and it is working for Vodafone phone still but not samsung I don't think that is the correct fix